# how to select a file by default when open a folder in vfp 9.0

Tags: file, directory, visual-foxpro

I want to open a folder, and select a file by default.

I do it like this:

```
Declare Long WinExec In kernel32 String @, Integer
WinExec("Explorer /select, C:\tt.txt",5)
```

But if the folder has been opened, the file can't be selected by default.

How to do it?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make sense to me. You can't open a folder in VFP. Can you clarify what you mean a bit please.

Answer (score 1):

What is your purpose of prompting a user with picking a particular file...

The closest you can get from wthin VFP is "GetFile()" where you can give it a default extension of a file you are hoping to find and it brings up a file selection dialog.

lcFileSelected = GetFile( "Txt", "Caption left of combobox selection (but only shows about 16 chars)", "Button Caption", nOptionalButton )

where ex:
nOptionalButton
0 = no extra button at bottom right, just the OK, Cancel (where OK is overridden by the "Button Caption" sample above.

1 = OK, New, Cancel

2 = Ok, None, Cancel

If a value selected, you'll have the file name, otherwise blank.

REVISED ANSWER..

Then what you want is PUTFILE() which allows you to prompt a user a simple message, similar to a "Save to", and allows to put a fully qualified path and file name.  Upon return, much like that of doing GETFILE() will return the final path/file name entered by the user.  Ex:

lcUserAnswer = PUTFILE( "save where", "C:\program files\myTest.txt" )

now you can do whatever with the "lcUserAnswer" variable...

Comment: Thanks for your answer

I just want to achieve a functions like operating system
For example:
Right-click a shortcut icon for a program on the desktop, select properties,left-click "Find target" button in the Properties window

When the window is opened, the EXE file was selected by default

Comment: My email:zhan0926@yahoo.com.cn

Comment: @lichaoz, see revised answer with PUTFILE()

Comment: Sorry,these are not what I need. I just need when a folder opened, a file was selected by default. Just like [WinExec("Explorer /select, C:\tt.txt",5)]